# Movie with medley of love songs being watched in Veronica Faith video

Tags: identify-this-song, music-video

Does anyone know the name of the music or movie :\

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HnabcI4zQFA

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the "Elephant Love Medley" from *[Moulin Rouge](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VxLaO8Xzjsk)* (2001) movie.

The music is a medley of famous love songs, including:

> I Will Always Love You by Whitney Houston
>   Your Song by Elton John
>   Pride (In the Name of Love) by U2
>   Silly Love Songs by Paul McCartney
>   All You Need Is Love by The Beatles
>   "Heroes" by David Bowie
>   Don't Leave Me This Way by Harold Melvin & The Blue Notes (Ft. Teddy Pendergrass)
>   Up Where We Belong (Love Theme from "An Officer and a Gentleman") by Joe Cocker
>   Love Is Like Oxygen by Sweet
>   One More Night by Phil Collins
>   Love Is A Many Splendoured Thing by Connie Francis
>   https://genius.com/Moulin-rouge-elephant-love-medley-lyrics